# autoFill registration form in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

i have data in my data array from webservices, i want to autofill all data when user enter email, it should load all data in all textfields , what should i do? please help

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    GET_DBHANDLER
    if (dataArray.count==0) {
        NSLog(@"sasas");
    }
    else
    {
    dataArray = [dbHandler getUserDetails:txtEmail.text];
    for (userDC *user in dataArray) {
        txtFirstName.text = user.firstName;
        txtSurName.text = user.surName;
        txtTelephone.text = user.telephone;
        txtMobile.text = user.mobile;
        txtBusinessName.text = user.businessName;
        txtBusinessAddress.text = user.business_address;
        txtWebSite.text = user.website;
        txtLinkedIn.text = user.linkedin;
        txtFaceBook.text = user.facebook;
        txtTwitter.text = user.twitter;
        txtAppUserName.text = user.app_username;
        txtAppPassword.text = user.app_password;
        txtNetworkUserName.text = user.network_username;
        txtNetworkPassword.text = user.network_password;
        txtBNIUserName.text = user.bni_username;
        txtBNIPassword.text = user.bni_password;
    }}

}
```

Comment: is there any button action or resigning keyboard or anything else for knowing data which is entered in textfield is completed or not?

Comment: no it should come from textfield

Comment: after entering email you want to fill the remaining textfields right?

Comment: yes exactly i want this

Comment: then tell me one thing how can we know wheather the email text was completely filled or not ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27694/discussion-between-sunny-and-quality-coder)

Comment: he will register first then in setting we will show auto fill when he will enter email

Comment: ok im getting your requirement but what im asking is if user wants enter test@gmail.com then after entering the test@gmail.com then only autofill is there if he enters wrong email then what will happend?

Comment: it will show nothing coz i have check that array.count ==0 show nothing

Comment: @Sunny wat r u thinking

Comment: @Nag_iphone:asalu vadiki kavalasindhi teliste ga manam edho okati cheyadaniki.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.tag == yourEmailTextField.tag)
    {
        if([textField.text isEqualToString:yourRequiredEmailID])
        {
            for (userDC *user in dataArray) {
                txtFirstName.text = user.firstName;
                txtSurName.text = user.surName;
                txtTelephone.text = user.telephone;
                txtMobile.text = user.mobile;
                txtBusinessName.text = user.businessName;
                txtBusinessAddress.text = user.business_address;
                txtWebSite.text = user.website;
                txtLinkedIn.text = user.linkedin;
                txtFaceBook.text = user.facebook;
                txtTwitter.text = user.twitter;
                txtAppUserName.text = user.app_username;
                txtAppPassword.text = user.app_password;
                txtNetworkUserName.text = user.network_username;
                txtNetworkPassword.text = user.network_password;
                txtBNIUserName.text = user.bni_username;
                txtBNIPassword.text = user.bni_password;
            }
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```